# Exception in case statement

Tags: psql, business-logic

How would you throw an exception in a case statement? I believe `signal` is the correct statement. The case statement is when the word 'corp' is found in the name then have a 1 in the column but I want an exception if the word 'dollar' is in the name

```
Name                     Is_comp
Dollar Tree Corp       
First Hand Corp           1

Select 
when name like 'corp' 
then 1 
end as is_comp
```

Comment: This would be a very odd thing to do in a SQL statement. What's your end game here? This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: Basically I have a list of names that I need to manually sort out and determine if the name is a company or a person. I'm trying to somewhat filter common names of companies like LLC, INC, CO. But sometimes I run into problems like company name "Dollar Tree Inc" and person name "Finch" I need to make an exception when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think, based on what you are looking for, you just need a fancier CASE statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            name LIKE ANY ('%corp%','%llc%','%inc%') /*list of names with wildcards*/
            AND name not like '%Finch%' /*don't match on finch%/ 
            AND name not like ANY ('%Finch%','%Brian%') /*or optionally don't match on any of these name substrings*/
            THEN 1 
        END 'is_comp'
FROM <table>
```

Comment: So in that case, you have INC. I would not want Finch to be included as 1 in the column. Right now, you have INC as %inc% meaning everything with INC will be included. I want to exclude Finch

Comment: Still the same idea. I have updated the answer to exclude finch (either individually or in a list)

Comment: Is there another way I can put the `LIKE` statements in a list?